# Add a column with the names of other columns as variables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My goal is to add a column with header name "phase", which will accommodate the name of the columns 'phase A', 'phase B', 'phase C'.

I want to be able to compare the 'sample date' with the dates of phase A and B and C. Depending on the location of the 'sample date' on the timeline, I want to return the phase during which the sample was taken.

Assume this dataframe:

```
phases=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['blue','red','yellow'], \
'sample date':['2018-05-23','2018-06-08','2018-06-01'], \
'phase A':['2018-03-22','2018-03-16','2018-03-09'], \
'phase B':['2018-06-02','2018-04-29','2018-05-19'], \
'phase C':['2018-09-30','2018-09-25','2018-09-12']})

phases['sample date']=pd.to_datetime(phases['sample date'])
phases['phase A']=pd.to_datetime(phases['phase A'])
phases['phase B']=pd.to_datetime(phases['phase B'])
phases['phase C']=pd.to_datetime(phases['phase C'])
#    (I failed to convert all 4 columns to_datetimes in one row)
```

If 'phase B' > 'sample date' >= 'phase A', then the new column should have 'phase A'.
If 'sample date' >= 'phase C', then the value should be 'phase C'.
If 'sample date' < 'phase A', then the value should be False or Nan.
For the above example, the output should be:

```
  ID sample date    phase A    phase B    phase C    phase
0  A  2018-05-23 2018-03-22 2018-06-02 2018-09-30  phase A
1  B  2018-06-08 2018-03-16 2018-04-29 2018-09-25  phase B
2  C  2018-06-01 2018-03-09 2018-05-19 2018-09-12  phase B
```

Is there a nice solution for this?
I am trying to combine `lookup` and `where`, but I am not even sure if I am in the correct direction. Any ideas more than welcome, thank you!

Comment: where do `phase B` come from? also, are `phase A,B,C` always increasing in that order?

Comment: Phase A, B, C and so on are in an increasing order and they come from the headers of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

In case your phases date are sorted increasingly:

```
s3 = phases['sample date'].ge(phases['phase C'])
s2 = phases['sample date'].ge(phases['phase B'])
s1 = phases['sample date'].ge(phases['phase A'])

phases['phase'] = np.select((s3,s2,s1), ('Phase C', 'Phase B', 'Phase A'), np.nan)
```

Output:

```
       ID sample date    phase A    phase B    phase C    phase
0    blue  2018-05-23 2018-03-22 2018-06-02 2018-09-30  Phase A
1     red  2018-06-08 2018-03-16 2018-04-29 2018-09-25  Phase B
2  yellow  2018-06-01 2018-03-09 2018-05-19 2018-09-12  Phase B
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `.ge`, I need to google it. But thanks for this `select` method that I did not know. I will try it at my dataset and let you know.

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang. However, in my real dataset, the column headers are really long. Is there a way that the names of the columns could be picked automatically?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `np.select`

```
con1=(phases['sample date']>=phases['phase A'])&(phases['sample date']<phases['phase B'])
con2=(phases['sample date']>=phases['phase C'])
con3=(phases['sample date']<phases['phase A'])
np.select([con1,con2,con3],['A','C',np.nan])
```

Comment: I was not familiar with `select` until this answer. I will apply it and will let you know this worked Many thanks, @WeNYoBen